# Tell npm to look for node_modules inside a different dir

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, node-modules

`npm` looks for `node_modules` in the current directory, and all its parent directories, then looks in the global location. My current proposed dir structure is:

- global

  - package.json
  - node_modules/
- project-1

  - gulpfile.coffee
- project-2

  - gulpfile.coffee

But this isn't where `npm` normally looks for this. Is there an environment variable I can set to deal with this, or a way I can tell it to look in a specific directory? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you move your projects into `global` subfolder?

Comment: To explain a bit further, this is inside a WordPress project, so I'm using the typical "themes/project-1", "themes/project-2" approach for loading these in and want to keep all of my dependency stuff (I'll also be putting bower components into this) in one, central location.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to set NODE_PATH in gulp.

```
.pipe(preprocess({context: { NODE_PATH: '$NODE_PATH:/path/to/other/dir'}}))
```

A full example would look like the following.

```
var preprocess = require('gulp-preprocess');

gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src('./app/*.html')
    .pipe(preprocess({context: { NODE_PATH: '$NODE_PATH:/path/to/other/dir'}})) //To set environment variables in-line 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

The above 2 examples add to the node path if it is set.  If you want to just set it do the following.

```
.pipe(preprocess({context: { NODE_PATH: '/path/to/other/dir'}}))
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Is there a way to do this without having to use preprocess inside of each gulp task? The issue I'm running into is when running `gulp` from `project-1` it's not finding the path to gulp, so it errors out still.

Comment: I don't think so...  What do you mean its not finding `gulp`?

Comment: If I try to set the `NODE_PATH` inside a gulp task, NPM still won't know what `gulp` is because where gulp is stored is outside of the normal scope of where NPM looks for `node_modules`, hence the reasoning for trying to set it initially in the file as a dependency before gulp is even run.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`NODE_PATH`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) environment variable you can set.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did come across that, but am not sure how that'd be set inside my gulpfile. I saw [gulp-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess), but think this is a bit overkill to add to each task as I want to set it globally.