# Copy node_module dist files in a gulpfile

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, npm, gulp

I'm building a WordPress theme using Bootstrap in which I'm using npm to manage the version of bootstrap used.

Because in WordPress it is best practise to enqueue scripts I need a method to copy Bootstraps node_modules dist js file to my theme for me to enqueue.

I'm currently referencing the file by traversing back through the file structure. Is there a more reliable technique to get the path of the node_modules folder which will work if the tree structure changes?

```
/* --- Vendor js compile --- */
gulp.task('vendor-js', function() {
    return gulp.src('../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js')
        .pipe(newer(folder.src + 'js/vendor'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.src + 'js/vendor'))
});
```

EDIT:

I've since changed my setup to define a variable at the start of the gulpfile, this means I'll only need to change it once but it isn't as dynamic as I would've hoped.

```
/* --- Folders --- */
const
    folder = {
        src: 'src/',
        dist: 'dist/',
        root: '../../../' // This is relative to the project root from the gulpfile
};

/* --- Libraries to include --- */
const
    vendor = [
        folder.root + 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js',
        folder.root + 'node_modules/rellax/rellax.js'
];

/* --- Vendor js compile --- */
gulp.task('vendor-js', function() {
    return gulp.src(vendor)
        .pipe(newer(folder.src + 'js/vendor'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.src + 'js/vendor'))
});
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "when the tree structure changes". Are you asking whether there is a dynamic method for determining the node_modules directory? You could set an environment variable as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132387/tell-npm-to-look-for-node-modules-inside-a-different-dir)

Comment: @Jamie_D Yes, so if the gulpfile get's put in a sub-folder the path currently declared wouldn't resolve to the right area. I've included a better workflow in my question but it is still not dynamic.